# Numpy argsort, sorting on first number

Tags: python, numpy

I've got the following code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([["value1", "value2", 3, "value4", "value5"],
             ["value1", "value2", -10, "value4", "value5"],
             ["value1", "value2", 31, "value4", "value5"],
             ["value1", "value2", 5, "value4", "value5"],
             ["value1", "value2", 3, "value4", "value5"]])

print("Default")
print(a)

a = a[a[:, 2].argsort()]

print()
print("Sorted:")
print(a)
```

This results in the following output:

```
Sorted:
[['value1' 'value2' '-10' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '3' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '3' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '31' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '5' 'value4' 'value5']]
```

But what I'm looking for is for the function to output this:

```
Sorted:
[['value1' 'value2' '-10' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '3' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '3' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '5' 'value4' 'value5']
 ['value1' 'value2' '31' 'value4' 'value5']]
```

When I change the 31 value to 51, it outputs correctly. So numpy is basically sorting on the first character of the number. But I can't find how to make it sort on the entire number.

Comment: Your values inside the numpy array are strings, they are sorted lexicographically. `'31' < '34' < '5' < '51'`

Comment: What is the type of your values in the np.array? all of them are ints or do you have a mix of ints and strings?

Comment: You must convert third column to integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the values you are sorting are strings. Change

```
a = a[a[:, 2].argsort()]
```

to

```
a = a[a[:, 2].astype(np.int).argsort()]
```

So that they are compared as integers.

Answer (score 1):

You must **convert the third column to integer**.

Look at here:

```
a = ['5']
b = ['31']
if a[0] > b[0]:
    print("{} is bigger than {}".format(a[0], b[0]))

Out[0]: 5 is bigger than 31

a = int(a[0])
b = int(b[0])
if b > a:
    print("{} is bigger than {}".format(b, a)) 

Out[1]: 31 is bigger than 5
```

For this reason, follow this:

```
 import numpy as np

 a = np.array('your array')
 a = a[a[:, 2].astype(np.int).argsort()]
```