# Sort a dict based on numbered keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort a dict based on keys that have a pattern like "[0-9]+_[A-Z]+". I would like it to be ordered by ascending number.

Here is where I am for the moment :

```
import operator
myDict = {
        '120_str' : 'value',
        '150_str' : 'value',
        '110_str' : 'value',
        '80_str' : 'value',
        '10_str' : 'value',
        '20_str' : 'value'
        }

sortedDict = sorted(myDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

What I actually have :

```
sortedDict = {
        '10_str' : 'value',
        '110_str' : 'value',
        '120_str' : 'value',
        '150_str' : 'value',
        '20_str' : 'value',
        '80_str' : 'value'
        }
```

What I would like to have :

```
sortedDict = {
        '10_str' : 'value',
        '20_str' : 'value',
        '80_str' : 'value',
        '110_str' : 'value',
        '120_str' : 'value',
        '150_str' : 'value'
        }
```

Comment: dictionaries do not have an order, they are unsorted... use a different structure like a `list`
python 3.7 guarantees the order is same as the insertion order, but I advise you to use OrderedDict instead to make it more clear

Comment: **This answer is here:** [Sorting dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262754/numpy-argsort-sorting-on-first-number/48263336#48263336)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `_` separated first element (`int`) as the sorting key:

```
sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[0]))
```

Use `collections.OrderedDict` to maintain the ordering:

```
collections.OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[0])))
```

**Example:**

```
In [109]: sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[0]))
Out[109]: 
[('10_str', 'value'),
 ('20_str', 'value'),
 ('80_str', 'value'),
 ('110_str', 'value'),
 ('120_str', 'value'),
 ('150_str', 'value')]

In [110]: collections.OrderedDict(sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[0])))
Out[110]: 
OrderedDict([('10_str', 'value'),
             ('20_str', 'value'),
             ('80_str', 'value'),
             ('110_str', 'value'),
             ('120_str', 'value'),
             ('150_str', 'value')])
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you all guys for all these solutions!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> def key(s):
...     n, s = s.split('_', 1)
...     return int(n), s
... 
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([(k, myDict[k]) for k in sorted(myDict, key=key)])
OrderedDict([('10_str', 'value'),
             ('20_str', 'value'),
             ('80_str', 'value'),
             ('110_str', 'value'),
             ('120_str', 'value'),
             ('150_str', 'value')])
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this? you can filter digits from the string and sort your dictionary based on that.

this also **doesn't** require you to **split** using a particular character. just in case if your key structure changes this would still work.

```
sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda t: int(filter(str.isdigit, t[0])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
sortedDict = {
    '10_str' : 'value',
    '110_str' : 'value',
    '120_str' : 'value',
    '150_str' : 'value',
    '20_str' : 'value',
    '80_str' : 'value'
    }

final_data = sorted(sortedDict.items(), key=lambda x:int(re.findall('^\d+', x[0])[0]))
```

Output:

```
[('10_str', 'value'), ('20_str', 'value'), ('80_str', 'value'), ('110_str', 'value'), ('120_str', 'value'), ('150_str', 'value')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, assuming output is a list of tuples. Dictionaries are not considered to be ordered, although they may be in the future.

Sort after converting to `int`, then add back the string formatting:

```
myLst = [(str(k)+'_str', v) for k, v in \
         sorted([(int(k.split('_')[0]), v) for k, v in myDict.items()])]

# [('10_str', 'value'),
#  ('20_str', 'value'),
#  ('80_str', 'value'),
#  ('110_str', 'value'),
#  ('120_str', 'value'),
#  ('150_str', 'value')]
```